# How to get the clock to display time in my timezone again?

Tags: 16.10, time, clock

After updating from 16.04 to 16.10, the time displayed by the clock in the top right corner has been changed from my local timezone to UTC. How can I change it back?

Running `$ date` prints out my local time correctly, with my local timezone listed. In the Time & Date settings menu, the "Set the time" option is set to "Manually" and my local time appears in the box below. Changing the time listed in the box has no effect. Likewise, checking the "Automatically from the internet" box does nothing and "Manually" is again selected if I close the menu and reopen it.

Comment: Changing the time manually through date and time settings should fix the problem. Try pressing Enter when you have set the time correctly in the settings. :)

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. Changing the time in the Time & Date settings doesn't do anything (even if I press enter afterwards).